# Comparison operator return 0 ==

Tags: php

I am reading a book and the author is using the following function. I don't understand the benefit of the equal operator. Can anybody please explain the reason for using the equal operator.

```
public function isDiscounted()
{
return 0 == $this->getRow()->discountPercent ? false : true;
}
```

Would it not be easier to go for

```
public function isDiscounted()
{
return $this->getRow()->discountPercent ? false : true;
}
```

?

Best regards, 
Herbert

Comment: it would, as long as discountpercentage returns boolean like value. The former is better to read and understand in the future

Comment: The "benefit" of the operator is to make it clear that you're comparing the discount percent with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of the `==` operator is to make the program's intent clearer, that you're comparing a numeric variable with zero. It's equivalent to writing:

```
if (0 == $this->getRow()->discountPercent) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

You could also write it as:

```
return $this->getRow()->discountPercent ? true : false;
```

but this suggests that `discountPercent` is a boolean value, not numeric. Similarly, you could write:

```
return !$this->getRow()->discountPercent;
```

but this also suggests that it's boolean. While PHP is flexible with types like this, treating all non-falsy values as true, the original code is easier for human readers to understand.

Answer (score 4):

In your example you would need to swap the true and false:

```
return $this->getRow()->discountPercent ? true : false;
```

However you could just cast the integer return to a boolean:

```
return (bool)$this->getRow()->discountPercent;
```

Or even:

```
return 0 != $this->getRow()->discountPercent;
```

There's no need for the ternary returning true or false.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do a loose comparison or a strict comparison. It really depends what you are trying to compare for, sometimes the loose is fine, sometimes you need it to be strict.

> loose vs strict

```
/** loose **/
0 == 0; // true
0 == false; // true
0 == ''; // true
0 == null; // true

/** strict **/
0 === 0; // true
0 === false; // false
0 === ''; // false
0 === null; // false
```

> as it pertains to your example

```
/**
 * When doing the loose comparison, anything is isn't
 * 0, false, '', or null will always evaluate to true.
 *
 * So for instance:
*/

'iamateapot' == true; // true
'false' == true; // true, this is true because it's a string of false not a boolean of false;
 0 == true; // false;
```

In your particular case you are doing

```
$this->getRow()->discountPercent ? false : true;
```

Which is doing a loose comparison, my preference is to always specify what you are comparing against, so your first example would be what I would personally choose.

Comment: What does this have to do with whether you can leave out the comparison entirely? Leaving it out is like the loose comparison.

Comment: I amended to include an example as it pertains to the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not easier to go for

```
return $this->getRow()->discountPercent ? false : true
```

In fact, it's wrong. You are supposed to return false if discountPercent is zero. In your suggested code, if discountPercent is zero, it will evaluate to false since it's used as a condition and return true.

If you truly want to keep the same logic but make it shorter the best way to go about it would be:

```
return $this->getRow()->discountPercent != 0
```

I have a rule I always follow: If the result of a conditional statement is a boolean, then return/condition itself. Also, I disagree that writing:

```
return 0 == $this->getRow()->discountPercent ? false : true;
```

makes the code more readable. If we go by what the function is supposed to do, I would write it something like this:

```
return $this->getRow()->discountPercent > 0
```

which clearly indicates that if discountPercent has a value greater than zero then it is discounted. Simple, precise and clear. It also takes care of negative values then.